# Limit problem using logarithm

Tags: limits

I have the following limit to evaluate: 
$$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}a^{\frac{r^{n+1}-1}{r(r-1)}}$$
Where $0<a,r<1$. 
Here is my attempt:

First, I took the logarithm of the limit, giving $\frac{r^{n+1}-1}{r(r-1)}\ln (a)$. Then, I let $r=\frac{1}{R}$ as it is less than $1$, and tried using L'Hoptial's rule, but it didn't work out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{r^{n+1}-1}{r(r-1)}=\dfrac{0-1}{r(r-1)}=\dfrac{1}{r(1-r)}$, no L'Hopital is involved.

The final answer is simply $a^{1/[r(1-r)]}$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $a^x$ is continuous pass the limit to the exponent term and use that fact that for $0<r<1$,

$\lim_{{n}\rightarrow\infty}r^{n+1}=0$